# CircleCI: comma separated files for parallel tests

Tags: arguments, continuous-integration, protractor, circleci, specs

It's very easy to setup parallel tests for rspec or cucumber on CircleCI:

```
test:
  override:
    - bundle exec rspec:
        parallel: true
        files:
          - spec/unit/sample.rb   # can be a direct path to file
          - spec/**/*.rb          # or a glob (ruby globs)
```

However I try to split protractor tests. It takes comma separated files as a command line argument instead of space separated files. How can I achieve this without too much work?

Comment: That didn't quite work for me, received an error about an invalid override type from Circle. However, this did work:

`test:\n
  override:\n
    - bundle exec cucumber features/deals/pay.feature`

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the following to your circle.yml:

```
test:
  override:
    - run () { echo $@ | tr ' ' ',' | xargs protractor; }; run:
        parallel: true
        files: ..
```

Comment: I try with more clean way, with rake task and without using bash, but it's hard to pass arguments with spaces to rake task as well.

Comment: Hmm, this is what I get:

run () { echo $@ | tr ' ' ',' | xargs `npm run protractor-specs`; }; run 'spec/javascripts/e2e/company_spec.coffee' 'spec/javascripts/e2e/facebook_spec.coffee' 'spec/javascripts/e2e/locale_spec.coffee'
/home/ubuntu/sim/node_modules/protractor/lib/cli.js:112
  var patterns = list.split(',');
                      ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function